# How to manage version number through GitHub desktop application?

Tags: github, version-control, versioning, github-for-windows, semantic-versioning

Is is possible to manage version number of a repository with GitHub Desktop Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Versioning in GitHub Desktop is very simple.

1. Commit your changes
2. Click on `History` Tab
3. Right Click on a commit history
4. Select `Create Tag...`
5. Now, write the version and select `Create tag`

The `Tag` hence created will be displayed as like this:

[image]

The **versioning Semantics** is well described [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46434732/9496122)